# Activate the Scan Text feature on a button tap - Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

Is there a way to activate the `Scan Text` feature you get when you long-press on a `TextField`?

This feature is awesome as is but most users don't know about this feature so adding a button that says `Scan` somewhere close to the text field would be helpful for the user.

Any idea how can this be triggered?

```
    HStack{
        TextField("Service Name", text:$serviceFieldName)
        Button("Scan"){
            // show Scan Text feature
        }
    }
    .padding()
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69322939/get-live-text-when-press-button/69324686#69324686